# Using external disk connected to RPI as time machine

Tags: hard-drive, macos, netatalk

I have tried to use [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/276468/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-networked-time-machine-drive-for-your-mac/) to use an external hard disk connected to a Raspberry Pi as a time machine. It succeeded in that I have made the Raspberry Pi visible on my mac, so that I am able to connect to "Time Machine" here. However, the size of this disk is app. 120 GB, which is equivalent to the memory card of the Pi. I would expect that it would be equivalent to 1TB, which is the size of the external hard disk.

I have tried to undo everything and follow the guide again, but the problem still persists. I have also tried to verify that the disk permissions on the external disk are correct, i.e. 777.

A speculative hypothesis is that I have somewhere mixed the memory card of the Pi and the external disk, but not sure how to verify this.

Any hints on where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you failed to mount the drive in the right place (in your guide that's `/media/tm`). Without the mount in place your mounpoint (the directory where you want to mount the drive) is just a regular directory on the SD card, that's why you see the disk size of your SD card when you're trying to use it.

I suggest you try to make a backup from your Mac (is it possible to backup a single file?) and check where the backup files are created on the SD card. Then run the `mount` command and check to which directory your drive is mounted. Hopefully you'll see a discrepancy, and your issue will be resolved once you correct it.

Comment: Yes! Also found out that I have put sda and not sda2 in fstab, so efter a restart, a umount -a and then a mount -a it worked...